# Leer un arreglo 2d en un archivo txt y convertirlo a una lista en Python conservando sus variables

Tags: python, array, lista, txt, read

Quisiera que mi código leyera un archivo txt con el siguiente formato:

```
7 3
31 18
19 36
55 63
21 29
14 58
18 54
22 25
```

En donde la primera línea representa las variables n (7) y p (3), y a partir de la siguiente línea son coordenadas que deben de ir juntas, para esto intenté una lista pero el problema es que con la sintaxis de leer valores en un archivo txt no respeta que las variables deben de ser x & y, por ejemplo, en la segunda línea x es 31 & su y es 18.

¿Existe alguna manera para hacer esto posible? De la manera que se muestra en mi código solo me permite guardar x & y en una sola variable dentro del objeto, lo cuál es inconveniente ya que necesitaré accesar ambos.

Nota: En las líneas de n y p se puede apreciar que el código está incompleto, esto es porque por el momento ningún método me ha servido según mis espeficiaciones. Una disculpa si no me pude expresar tan bien, adjunto el código:

```
import numpy as np

#reading the file parameters
fileName = open('outputfile1.txt','r')
linesBeforeData = 0

main_array = []

class Array: 
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = y
        self.x = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{:f} : {:f} : {:f}'.format(self.x, self.y)

#converting the parameters intro int variables


n = #esta línea está incompleta porque no supe cómo programarlo según mis requerimientos
p = #esta línea está incompleta porque no supe cómo programarlo según mis requerimientos
for line in fileName:
    line = line.strip()
    linesBeforeData += 1
    if line=="Data:": break
    x = [item.strip() for item in line.split(" ")]
    y = [item.strip() for item in line.split(" ")]
    main_array.append(Array(x,y))
```

Comment: quieres que la variable `n` y `p` sean 2 listas cada una o que simplemente sea un array bidimensional??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en

```
def __init__(self, x,y):
    self.x = y
    self.x = y
```

Inicializas `self.x` con `y` dos veces y  nunca inicializas `self.y`.

Aquí el formato menciona tres reemplazos, pero sólo pasas dos valores:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{:f} : {:f} : {:f}'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

#### Solución

Partimos por definir correctamente la clase `Array`

```
class Array:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} : {} '.format(self.x, self.y)
```

Luego definimos una función auxiliar que toma una línea y extrae dos valores enteros, devolviendo una tupla:

```
def extraer_valores(linea):
    a, b = linea.split()
    return int(a), int(b)
```

Para procesar el archivo, usare la forma `with open() as nombre:`, que es más conveniente pues cierra automáticamente el archivo al terminar:

```
#reading the file parameters
with open('outputfile1.txt','r') as archivo:
    main_array = []

    n, p = extraer_valores(archivo.readline())
    for line in archivo.readlines():
        if line == "Data:":
            break
        x, y = extraer_valores(line)
        main_array.append(Array(x, y))
```

Lo primero es extraer los valores `n` y `p` de la primera línea. Para leerla uso `readline()` (singular).

A continuación itero leyendo sobre las siguientes líneas, devueltas con `readlines()` (plural).

En cada línea extraigo los valores `x` e `y`, instancio un nuevo elemento y lo agrego a la lista en formación.

#### Demo

```
class Array:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} : {} '.format(self.x, self.y)

def extraer_valores(linea):
    a, b = linea.split()
    return int(a), int(b)

#reading the file parameters
with open('outputfile1.txt','r') as archivo:
    main_array = []

    n, p = extraer_valores(archivo.readline())
    for line in archivo.readlines():
        if line == "Data:":
            break
        x, y = extraer_valores(line)
        main_array.append(Array(x, y))

print("n={}, p={}".format(n, p))
for coord in main_array:
    print(coord)

print("n={}, p={}".format(n, p))
for coord in main_array:
    print(coord)
```

produce:

```
n=7, p=3
31 : 18 
19 : 36 
55 : 63 
21 : 29 
14 : 58 
18 : 54 
22 : 25 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto solucionará el problema, lo implementaré al código y realmente veo que todo está bien.